# REGEX work for initial space with string

Tags: apex, class, regular-expressions

I have a requirement to find a string('Mc') which either present at begining of the field value or after a space. Can someone help as my code fails for 'hemchand'.

REGEX Code:

```
AND(REGEX(FirstName&' ' &LastName,".*((?i)Mc)[a-z].*"), IsPersonAccount =TRUE)
```

String: Mc

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this pattern: `M[Cc]'?[A-aZ-z]{1,}`

Here's a good site for you to test your expressions before using them in your code: http://www.regexr.com/

Also, bear in mind that this question isn't Salesforce-specific, so you could have asked it on another community (like the [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) community).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different pattern to try using http://regexr.com/. I think your regex should look more like the following:

```
(i?)(\s?(mc)\s)
```

The `(i?)` at the beginning of the pattern sets a global flag to make the search case insensitive. The `(\s?(mc)\s)` provides for an optional blank space followed by an `mc` (any combination of upper or lower case) and an additional space. You can make the additional space optional by changing the `\s` at the end to a `\s?`.